# Strange return of RangeOfString method

Tags: objective-c, nsrange

Little explanation of the code : I have a dict that looks like this :

```
HC_1 : test1, HC_2: test2, ....
```

If I find HC_1 in the "theModifiedReportTemplateContent", I look for the first ">" after and I add "test1".

```
 -(NSMutableString*)almMapData:(NSDictionary *)aDictData;
{

NSMutableString *theModifiedReportTemplateContent = itsReportTemplateContent mutableCopy];

for(id theCell in aDictData)
{
    NSRange theNameRange = [theModifiedReportTemplateContent rangeOfString:theCell];
    NSString *theNewContent = [theModifiedReportTemplateContent substringFromIndex:theNameRange.location];
    if(theNameRange.location != NSNotFound)
    {
        NSRange theCharRange = [theNewContent rangeOfString:@">"];
        long theIndex =((long)theCharRange.location+(long)theNameRange.location+1);
        [theModifiedReportTemplateContent insertString:[aDictData objectForKey:theCell] atIndex:theIndex];

    }
}

return theModifiedReportTemplateContent;

}
```

My problem is that we I print theCharRange, I have something like :

```
location=13, length=1
 {
  2001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000

  <object returned empty description>

}
```

So I have a exception with InsertString atIndex.

Comment: What does `itsReportTemplateContent` contain?

Comment: Html content like :
<tr height=16 style='height:16.0pt'>
  <td height=16 style='height:16.0pt'></td>
  <td class=xl74>&nbsp;</td>
  <td class=xl75>&nbsp;</td>
  <td class=xl75>&nbsp;</td>
  <td class=xl85><a name="HC_5">NPV &lt; 100 000</a></td>
  <td class=xl85 style='border-left:none'><a name="HC_6">NPV IN (100 000,200
  000)</a></td>
  <td class=xl86 style='border-left:none'><a name="HCA_7">NPV &gt;= 200 000</a></td>
  <td class=xl66>&nbsp;</td>
 </tr>

Comment: You might be better off parsing it using an XML parser, then modifying the DOM and then writing it back out.  Your current implementation is very ugly and error-prone.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I just discovered about NSXMLParser. Do you know how to use it ?